# Proper Way to Float Elements

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have the following HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Details</legend>

    <div class="form-section first">
        <div class="abc">
            <div class="editor-label">
                <label for .../>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input type="text" ... />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="def">
           ...
        </div>

        <div class="ghi">
           ...
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-section">

    </div>

    <div class="form-section last">
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I have a fieldset that is wrapping all of my form elements. The fieldset contains multiple form sections, which basically hold one "row" of content. The divs in the form sections I want to float to the left:

```
|||||||    |||||||      |||||||   <-- first form section, 3 floated elements

|||||||    |||||||||||            <-- second form section, 2 floated elements
```

What is the proper way to float these elements so that:

1) The second form section occurs on its own line.
2) The second form section can apply a top margin.

I can't seem to get it right. I need the solution to work in IE7. I tried putting a clear: both on the form-section element but it didn't seem to work right. All 5 elements occurred on the same line instead of 2 separate lines.

** EDIT **

I can somewhat get this to work. My issue is the following:
When I float the elements within a container, they essentially have 0 height. This messes up any containers that come after it if they want to apply a top margin.

Comment: Can you make a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have so far? And add your current CSS? Even if it's not doing what you want, it helps us to work out your intent.

Comment: Sure let me try and put that together quick.

Comment: Not trying to be dense, but why don't you just use a <br /> tag to line break the div sections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the row of three try:

```
<div style="clear:both; width:100%;">
    <div style="float: left;"></div>
    <div style="float: left;"></div>
    <div style="float: right;"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both; width:100%; height:10px;"></div>
<div style="clear:both; width:100%;">
    <div style="float: left;"></div>
    <div style="float: left;"></div>
</div>
```

That should get you the desired output.

Comment: This somewhat works. The one problem with this is the top margin doesn't work right. Since the first row is out of the flow it is ignoring the margin of it. For example...lets say I tell the first three floated items to have a height of 500px. Since they are floated, the form-section container doesn't know they are 500px, so it thinks its height is 0px, so margin isn't applied correctly

Comment: There is a hackish way to get around that problem, adding in a div between the two rows (as demonstrated in modified answer) with a fixed height will give you a margin

Answer (score 1):

```
<fieldset>
            <legend>Details</legend>
            <div id="section 1">
                <span style="height: 500px;">1</span>
                <span style="height: 500px;">2</span>
                <span style="height: 500px;">3</span>
            </div>

            <div id="section 2" style="margin-top: 50px;">
                <span>4</span>
                <span>5</span>
            </div>

</fieldset>
```